# Scan android devices around

Tags: android, wifi

I want to know is it possible with Android code to scan Android device with Wifi or data activated, and send them a pop up which contain a URL?

Comment: you can scan android devices if bluetooth or WiFI-hotspot is on into device.

Comment: are you trying to send them without their interactions ? then NO!   You can not. but if you want to send data it's possible with bluetooth/wifi/nfc etc